# finding content-type from wireshark

Tags: security, http-headers, mime-types, content-type, wireshark

Here are the wireshark logs of 3 POST's. All posting the same data but with different content-types, resulting in different ways the data is read on the server. I'm attempt to to understand how to create POST Z.

**POST X**
Explicitly setting form based post

[image]

gives [image]

**POST Y**
Omitted content-type

[image]

gives [image]

**POST Z** ?
My app is not able to reproduce this.

[image]

gives [image]

I'm attempting to guess what content-type in the last POST Z (notice there are no brackets), which made the post parameters appear as data ( and apparently without a data-type )

Thanks
~B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm attempting to guess what content-type in the last POST Z (notice there are no brackets), which made the post parameters appear as data ( and apparently without a data-type )

The content type is probably "none".

You're not *obliged* to send a Content-Type: header with a POST request.  The HTTP 1.1 spec, [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), says in [section 7.2.1 "Type"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7.2.1):

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, therecipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

It says SHOULD, not MUST, so a sender is *allowed* to send an entity-body without a Content-Type: header.